# Restricting ParseQuery by user text input

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, autocompletetextview

I'm trying to write a restriction to my ParseQuery whereby the query only returns usernames that contain the first two characters input by my user into the AutoCompleteTextView. Can I use substring to find the first two characters of the string input into AutoCompleteTextView, then run a query based on that?

```
    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.searchUserTextField);
        String input = textView.toString();
        String recommendation = input.substring(0,2);
        userQuery.whereStartsWith(ParseConstants.KEY_USERNAME, recommendation);
        userQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        ...
```

I realize this isn't really how you'd do this, and I haven't set up handlers to generate new queries based on how the text changes, but I'm trying to figure this out in baby steps.

Comment: When your code is indented with 11 tabs it's time to break things out into seperate functions. The logic is so deeply nested it is too hard to follow

Comment: @GregEnnis I reduced my question all the way down to its core components. I realize that was messy.

Comment: Other than you don't initialize `userQuery`, I don't see any problem with the code above. Are you getting an error or are you wanting to know if this is best? It seems it would work just fine. However, I would consider limiting your query results. Potentially that could return a lot of users.

Comment: @ChadBingham It's not returning an error and I initialized the query beforehand. I'll post what I ultimately came up with as an answer. I just wanted to know if this was efficient, at least for the purposes of a beginner on a small app. I realize I'll probably have to change this up in the future.

Comment: Make sure if you do it on text changed, you cancel previous query to avoid redundant queries overlapping

Comment: @IliiazAkhmedov How would I go about canceling previous queries? I posted my full code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have in the onCreate() method of my Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from listview_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    final AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.searchUserTextField);
    textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
            if (count % 2 == 1) {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textView.showDropDown();
                        UserSuggestionQuery(textView);
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            UserSuggestionQuery(textView);
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            UserSuggestionQuery(textView);
        }
    });
    textView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterview, View v,
                                   int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.searchUserTextField);
            textView.setText(adapterview.getItemAtPosition(position)
                    .toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    textView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
            UserSuggestionQuery(textView);
            return false;
        }
    });

    SubmitSearch();

    // Execute RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
    new RemoteDataTask().execute();

}
```

The following function appears in the above code. This is the actual query for the users input to the AutoCompleteTextView:

```
    private void UserSuggestionQuery(AutoCompleteTextView textView) {
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> userQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
        String input = textView.getText().toString();
        System.out.println(input);
        String recommendation = input.substring(0);
        userQuery.whereStartsWith(ParseConstants.KEY_USERNAME, recommendation);
        userQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(final List<ParseUser> parseUsers, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("users", "Retrieved " + parseUsers.size());

                    ParseUser[] data = parseUsers.toArray(new ParseUser[parseUsers.size()]);
                    String[] strings = new String[data.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        strings[i] = data[i].getString(ParseConstants.KEY_USERNAME).toLowerCase();
                    }
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings));
                    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item, strings);
                    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.searchUserTextField);
                    textView.showDropDown();
                    textView.setThreshold(1);
                    textView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    // Query based on text change
                    adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);

                }
            }
        });
    }
```